# HTTP Post vs URL Parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, post, https

I was hoping to get some clarification on how I should go about creating a HTTP Post for this particular project I am working on. This is all very new to me so forgive my ignorance.

Here is a link to the specifications for more information (Note this is publically available so im not sharing anything I shouldn't): [Specifications](https://portal.frontier.edu/documents/10609/255986/2176401_Tiwari_DL.pdf/abc6e379-78ee-e6c3-f4cc-ed61e40ccf25?version=1.0)

A GET method is also mentioned briefly in the specifications, would this be url parameter method?

Basically I am confused on whether or not I should be creating a url with parameters, and using this built out url to link users from our system to this third party interface.

Or should I create a HTTP POST Request with html parameters, and use the provided link with no parameters? Would that work? Would the link for my users to click just be "https://officialpayments.com/pc_entry_cobrand.jsp" in this example.

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Examples:

```
Dim URL as String = "https://officialpayments.com/pc_entry_cobrand.jsp?
language=en&cityName=Anytown&paymentAmount=700.43&provinceCd=GA&cdeBillYear-2=2013&lastName=Collins&source=pos&firstName=Randall&cdeBillNumb-1=1246777&productId=33926000594532589286695155978113093"

#I would then present this as a clickable link to end user
#OR Should I do Something similar to this:

Dim WebRequest request  = WebRequest.Create("https://staging.officialpayments.com/pc_template_standard.jsp")
request.Method = "POST"
Dim byteArray as byte[] = File("Post.html") #Assume this pulls back html to put into request 
request.ContentType = "text/html"
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
Dim WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
#Would https://officialpayments.com/pc_entry_cobrand.jsp be the link my users click??
```

Comment: Section 1, second paragraph. "The data is passed to the ACI site from the client site in an **HTTP POST** request that contains all the required fields. Communication back to the client site is also done using an **HTTP POST** over SSL.

Comment: On Page 7 under URL parameters, they do reference a GET method. So could both methods work for sending in the data? If I used a post, what URL would I provide to my end users?

Comment: Doesn't seem clear to me. I think you will need to contact the organization that drafted this document and owns the service.